# Is a GIS database necessary? Most efficient way?

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, geolocation

I have been tasked with finding an efficient way to store data of thousands of addresses to compare to a broader set of addresses of all retail stores in America. Ideally, I would like the database to be able to be used with quick queries to find closest surrounding properties, with certain parameters based on the supplementary data of all the addresses stored.

Should I be simply using a RDBMS or would a GIS be necessary for this?

Comment: Are you using a geocoding service to create points?

Comment: Are you putting this up on a portal? If not, I don't see this as an enterprise GDB. They are not needed (or faster) just because of large number of records. They are for portals and multi-editor situations.

Comment: Not sure what is meant by putting it to a portal. The plan would be to have multple users analyze and maniuplate with the database. I am beginning to learn geocoding to create points, however right now I just have lat/lng coordinates and address info

Comment: Why not have both?  Use postgresql with postgis.  Then you have both in one.

Answer (score 1):

I'm new to GIS myself; however, this sounds exactly like a huge use case of a GIS database. Proximity searches, etc can be done directly in SQL using them.

In a typical database, you would have to query the addresses and then write an algorithm to do this yourself. When the tools are out there, you don't have a good justification NOT to use a GIS database.

A popular open source one is PostGIS. It's PostgresQL with some additional plugins. For me with a background in software engineering it was the clear choice.

Comment: My experience so far has been mainly with MySQL. Is there a compatible GIS platform you might recommend or would it be worthwile to learn postgres/gis

Comment: I bought a book - PostGIS in Action - that was helpful. That's generally how I go about learning an entirely new concept.. in my case GIS & databases.. but that's just me! You'll probably figure out pretty quickly if it is really the right use case for you with a resource like that.